# Finding length of a list inside an object in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a function that uses len to find the length of a list that's an attribute of an object in python.

Here's my code:

```
class Supplement(object):
    def __init__(self, name, price, ingredients, certifications):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.certifications = certifications

    def print_certifications(self):
        print "The supplement %s has the following certifications:" % self.name
        for certification in self.certifications:
            if len(self.certifications) == 0:
                print "Sorry, no certifications for this product."
            else:
                print certification

UltimateProtein = Supplement("Ultimate Protein", 29.99, ["wheatgrass", "alfalfa grass",        
"probiotics"], ["organic", "vegan", "raw"])
UltimateFatLoss = Supplement("Ultimate Fat Loss", 39.99, ["lecithin", "chlorella", "spirulina"],         
[] )

UltimateProtein.print_certifications()
UltimateFatLoss.print_certifications()
```

When I execute the program I get the following output:

```
The supplement Ultimate Protein has the following certifications:
organic
vegan
raw

The supplement Ultimate Fat Loss has the following certifications:
```

I'd like that last line to read like this:

```
The supplement Ultimate Fat Loss has the following certifications:
Sorry, no certifications for this product.
```

What's preventing my code from using the for loop correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `for` loop body is not executed for empty list. (empty list; nothing to iterate)

Check the length outside of the `for` loop.

```
def print_certifications(self):
    print "The supplement %s has the following certifications:" % self.name
    if not self.certifications:  # len(self.certifications) == 0
        print "Sorry, no certifications for this product."
    for certification in self.certifications:
        print certification
```